# When it is possible to write a function as an infinite sum of $1/(z_\alpha - z)$ terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Is it possible that the equality
$$
\frac1{\exp(\epsilon z)-z} = \sum_\alpha \frac{A_\alpha}{z_\alpha - z}
$$
is valid for small enough complex $z$?

Here $z_\alpha$ are roots of $\exp(\epsilon z) = z$ equation, $\epsilon$ is small (0.1 or 0.01) positive real parameter and
$$
A_\alpha = \lim_{z\to z_\alpha}\frac{z_\alpha-z}{\exp(\epsilon z)-z} = \frac1{1-\epsilon z_\alpha}.
$$

Analogous equalities are valid for $1/P(z)$ functions, where $P(z)$ is polynomial with non-degenerate zeros. When is it possible to write equalities of this kind for functions of a complex variable with an infinite number of zeros?

Comment: In general one needs absolute convergence of the sum $\sum 1/|z_n|$ or some symmetry that allows conditional uniform convergence by grouping

Comment: @Conrad, Inequality $\sum_n |A_n/z_n| < \infty$ or similar after sum rearrangement looks like a natural condition for an infinite sum to exist. Do you think this is enough? Are there any known theorems on this topic? I'm not too well versed in complex analysis to know such things.

Comment: The infinite sum gives then a meromorphic function with the appropriate poles/residues but one may need to add an entire function to get the original $1/f$; not sure if there is any general theory - remember seeing something about this in Boas entire functions book